# How to substring a char vector using patterns in R?

Tags: r, vector, char, substr

I have this kind of char vector:

```
"MODIS.evi.2013116.yL2.BOKU.tif"
```

The number in the middle of the vector is gonna change. And the `evi` word will change to `ndvi` some times.

I want to use `substr` (or other function, maybe) to sub-string the vector after the second point: `.`, ie, just take the `2013116.yL2.BOKU.tif`, even when the string is `MODIS.evi.2013116.yL2.BOKU.tif` or `MODIS.ndvi.2013116.yL2.BOKU.tif`.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296489/when-is-it-ok-to-extend-a-question-with-another-question-after-initial-answers

Comment: Eventually usefull material: `help("regex")` and http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html and http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/SvetlanaEdenRFiles/regExprTalk.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match two instance of one or more characters that are not a `.` followed by a `.` from the start (`^`) of the string and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
sub("^([^.]+\\.){2}", "", str1)
#[1] "2013116.yL2.BOKU.tif" "2013116.yL2.BOKU.tif"
```

If the pattern to keep always start with numbers, then the above can be simplified to match only one or more non-numeric characters and replace it with blank from the start (`^`) of the string

```
sub("^\\D+", "", str1)
#[1] "2013116.yL2.BOKU.tif" "2013116.yL2.BOKU.tif"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("MODIS.evi.2013116.yL2.BOKU.tif", "MODIS.ndvi.2013116.yL2.BOKU.tif")
```

Comment: Thanks. How would be if I want to take what is between the 2 points and put after BOKU? For example: MODIS.evi.2013116.yL2.BOKU.tif ==> 2013116.yL2.BOKU_evi.tif

Comment: @HugoBendini  You can capture as groups i.e. `sub("^[^.]+\\.([^.]+)\\.(.*)\\.([^.]+)$", "\\2_\\1.\\3", str1)
#[1] "2013116.yL2.BOKU_evi.tif"  "2013116.yL2.BOKU_ndvi.tif"`

Comment: Great! Could you please recommend me some material to learn how to use these regular expressions?

Answer (score 1):

```
l = c("MODIS.evi.2013116.yL2.BOKU.tif","MODIS.ndvi.2013116.yL2.BOKU.tif")
sapply(l, function(x) strsplit(x, "vi.", fixed = T)[[1]][2])
```

Comment: eventually `sapply()`. For an input like `c("MODIS.evi.2013116.vixyL2.BOKU.tif","MODIS.ndvi.2013116.yL2.BOKU.tif")` you need `fixed = TRUE`. Another variant is changing the two steps: `sapply(strsplit(l, "vi.", fixed = TRUE), '[[', 2)`

Comment: Thanks @Aleksandr Voitov! Please, how would be if I want to take what is between the 2 points and put after BOKU? For example: MODIS.evi.2013116.yL2.BOKU.tif ==> 2013116.yL2.BOKU_evi.tif

Answer (score 1):

This deletes all leading non-digit characters in `s` :

```
sub("^\\D*", "", s)
```

If `s` is as in the Note at the end then the result of running the above is:

```
[1] "2013116.yL2.BOKU.tif" "2013116.yL2.BOKU.tif"
```

**Note:**

```
s <- c("MODIS.evi.2013116.yL2.BOKU.tif", "MODIS.ndvi.2013116.yL2.BOKU.tif")
```

Comment: Thanks @G. Grothendieck! Please, how would be if I want to take what is between the 2 points and put after BOKU? For example: MODIS.evi.2013116.yL2.BOKU.tif ==> 2013116.yL2.BOKU_evi.tif

Comment: Try this: `with(read.table(text = s, sep = ".", as.is = TRUE), paste(V3, V4, V5, V2, V6, sep = "."))`